# Limit of a sequence $\sqrt[n]{3^{n+1}+2^n}$ using squeeze method

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Determine whether the sequence converges or not. If it does converge, find the limit.
>   $$a_n=\sqrt[n]{3^{n+1}+2^n}$$

I have seen a problem such as this but when it is $3^n$ and not $3^{n+1}$. So here is my work using squeeze.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{3^{n+1}+2^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{(3+(\frac23)^n)3^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}3\sqrt[n]{3+(\frac23)^n}$$

Now I try to setup a squeeze but I think this is where the issue lies.

$$1\le\sqrt[n]{3+(\frac23)^n}\le3+(\frac23)^n$$
$$\implies 3\le3\sqrt[n]{3+(\frac23)^n}\le3(3+(\frac23)^n)$$

As $n\to\infty$,

$3\to 3$ and $3(3+(\frac23)^n)\to9$

Any suggestions on setting up my squeeze would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you know that $\sqrt[n]4\to1$ (and you definitely should!) then you are done since $$3^n\leqslant3^{n+1}+2^n\leqslant3^{n+1}+3^n=4\cdot3^n$$ hence $$3\leqslant a_n\leqslant3\cdot\sqrt[n]4$$ which is ideally tailored for the squeeze theorem. (And no, no logarithm is needed here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
$$1\le\sqrt[n]{3+(\frac23)^n}\le \sqrt[n]{3+(1)^n}=\sqrt[n]{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on limits, but I think you can make use of the fact that $ln(x)$ is a continuous function.

Let's consider $ln(a_n)$: 
$$ln(a_n) = ln((3^{n+1} + 2^n)^{\frac{1}{n}})$$
$$ln(a_n) = \frac{1}{n}(3^n(3 + (\frac{2}{3})^n)$$
$$ln(a_n) = \frac{1}{n}ln(3^n) + \frac{1}{n}ln(3 + (\frac{2}{3})^n)$$
$$ln(a_n) = ln(3) + \frac{1}{n}ln(3 + (\frac{2}{3})^n)$$

As $n→∞$, $(\frac{2}{3})^n → 0$ and $\frac{1}{n}ln(3 + (\frac{2}{3})^n)→ 0$.

Hence, $$ln(a_n)→ln(3)$$ 
and 
$$a_n → 3$$